# How to restrict helo to match the client's ip/domain

Tags: postfix

Postfix has some nice options to restrict client accesses with respect to DNS/IP address setup and `helo` names ([documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_helo_restrictions)). For example one can instruct postfix to reject clients if

- the `helo` argument is a malformed domain
- the `helo` argument is not a fully qualified domain name
- the IP address has no reverse domain lookup entry
- the domain from the reverse lookup does not point to the client's IP address
- the domain has a MX entry

At least in my observation these measures are quite successful against some amount of spam.

What I am missing is a more strict reject option that works like this:

- reject if the DNS lookup of the `helo` argument does not match the client's IP address

AFAICS, there is no explicit option to configure this restriction. But perhaps there are other ways to configure that behavior with postfix?

Comment: I belive you are right – there is no such restriction. The closest would be `reject_unknown_hostname`.
I'm sure you can achieve checking DNS consistency with policy service.

Comment: @ScylddeFraud, you are referring to http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html ? Sounds like the way to go. If you post your comment as answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Did you end up implementing this somehow?

Comment: @Greendrake no, I didn't pursue this idea. I'm still using many smtpd restrictions such as `reject_unknown_client_hostname`, `reject_unknown_helo_hostname`, `reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname` and others. This is still very effective against spammers. So much so I don't need a more strict reject option, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive you are right – there is no such restriction. The closest would be `reject_unknown_hostname`. I'm sure you can achieve checking DNS consistency with policy services → http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html.

Answer (score 1):

I searched (the whole :) internet for the same question and ended up in this thread. I was already about to write my own policy server when I noticed that there exists a great one called [policyd-weight](http://www.policyd-weight.org/).

You should take a look at it because it implements even more than `HELO`-checking. For example DNSBLs with Scoring.